# Type Error while creating Nested Objects in Single Shot in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create a nested object in DRF, however, always end up with the following error:

```
    TypeError at /leads/lead/
    create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am trying to receive the data through a model viewset. Each lead is supposed to have genres, languages and businesses (all three are many to many fields).

This is my serializer create method:

```
    class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Language
            fields = "__all__"
    
    class GenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Genre
            fields = "__all__"
    
    class BusinessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Business
            fields = "__all__"

    class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        language_id = LanguageSerializer(many=True)
        genre_id = GenreSerializer(many=True)
        business_id = BusinessSerializer(many=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Lead
            fields = "__all__"
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            language_data = validated_data.pop("language_id")
            genre_data = validated_data.pop("genre_id")
            business_data = validated_data.pop("business_id")
    
            languages = []
            genres = []
            businesses = []
            lead = Lead.objects.create(**validated_data)
    
            for language in language_data:
                language_obj = Language.objects.create(language)
                lead.language_id.add(language_obj)
    
            for genre in genre_data:
                genre_obj = Genre.objects.create(genre)
                lead.genre_obj.add(genre_obj)
    
    
            for business in business_data:
                business_obj = Business.objects.create(business)
                lead.business_id.add(business_obj)
    
            return lead
```

Here are the models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
class Genre(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   ...

class Language(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 

class Business(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=BUSINESS_CHOICES, default="other")
    ...



class Lead(models.Model):
    ...
    genre_id                = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    language_id             = models.ManyToManyField(Language) 
    business_id             = models.ManyToManyField(Business)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says `create` takes keyword arguments but you are passing positional arguments.
`Genre.objects.create(genre)` is wrong. Instead you should have `Genre.objects.create(name=genre)` as the fields of the model are not ordered so it wouldn't know which field `genre` is. Same with `Language.objects.create(language)`